Infinite Sigma Algebra
Let $M$ be an infinite sigma algebra on some set $X$. Show that we can find an infinite sequence of disjoint sets in $M$.
So, there are probably easier ways to go about solving this but I was given a hint to solve it by defining an equivalence relation: for distinct $x,y \in X$ we define $x\sim y$ if and only if there exists proper subset $E\subset X$ and $E\in M$ such that $x,y \in E$.
I was able to show this is an equivalent relation. Now, if the partition of $X$ is infinite I am done. However, I couldn't argue that $X/\sim$ has to be infinite. But I was able to produce a proof that if $X/\sim$ is finite we can just choose an infinite part of the partition and repeat the equivalence argument with the subspace sigma algebra(The process would not end because $X$ is infinite. We can get an decreasing sequence of sets in the original sigma algebra, which we then can use to produce a sequence of disjoint sets).
But I wanted to ask does the partition produced by this equivalence relation must be infinite?   Thanks!

In a lot of “reasonable” situations, $X/\sim$ has just one element - this happens whenever all singleton subsets of $X$ are in $M$ (since then ${x, y} \in M$ for all $x, y \in X$), which happens for most sigma algebras arising in practice. This also means your approach when $X/\sim$ is finite does not work, as your “decreasing” sequence of sets is just going to be eventually constant.

(FWIW, I don’t understand this hint you were given. I could not see any way to use it the prove the desired result.)

@DavidGao I thought about that too, but it was required to be a proper subset that contains those points. So, the space $X$ itself doesnt count.

That doesn’t mean the equivalence class is not $X$? I don’t see your point. As an easy example, just take $X$ be an infinite set and $M = \mathcal{P}(X)$. Verify for yourself that $x \sim y$ for all $x, y \in X$.

As pointed out in David Gao's comments, the hint to define "an equivalence relation: for distinct $x,y \in X$ we define $x\sim y$ if and only if there exists proper subset $E\subset X$ and $E\in M$ such that $x,y \in E$" does NOT make sense. To add one more example: consider the Borel sigma-algebra on $\Bbb R$. For any distinct $x,y \in \Bbb R$, the set $\{x,y\}$ is Borel measurable and a proper subset of $\Bbb R$, so $x\sim y$. So $\Bbb R/\sim$ has just one equivalence class.
A good hint could be: Consider trying to assign to each $x \in X$ the smallest measurable $E_x$ such that $x \in E_x$. Let us prove the result using such hint.
Proof: Suppose that for each $x \in X$ there is a measurable set $E_x$ such that $x \in E_x$ and if $D$ is any measurable set such that $x \in D$, then $E_x \subseteq D$.
It is easy to see that, if $x , y \in X$ and $x \neq y$, then $E_x = E_y$ or $E_x \cap E_y=\emptyset$. In fact, if $x \in E_x \setminus E_y$, then $E_x \subseteq E_x \setminus E_y$, so $E_x \cap E_y=\emptyset$. In a similar way, if $y \in E_y \setminus E_x$, then $E_x \cap E_y=\emptyset$. Finally,
if $x , y \in E_x \cap E_y$, then $E_x \subseteq E_x \cap E_y$ and $E_y \subseteq E_x \cap E_y$, so $E_x = E_y$.
So, $\mathcal E= \{E_x : x \in X\}$ is a partition of $X$ by non-empty measurable  sets. Moreover, given any measurable set $F$, we have
$\mathcal E_F =\{E_x : x \in F\} \subseteq \mathcal E$ and $F= \bigcup_{E \in \mathcal E_F} E$. So, if $\mathcal E$ is finite, then $M$, the sigma-algebra,  is finite too, but $M$ is infinite, so $\mathcal E$ is infinite. It is immediate that, from $\mathcal E$, we can pick an infinite sequence of non-empty disjoint sets in $M$.
Now, suppose there is $x \in X$ such that, for all measurable $A$, if $ x\in A$, there is a measurable set $B$ such that $x \in B \subsetneq A$. Define $A_0=X$, and for each $i \in \Bbb N$, if $x \in A_i$, take a measurable $A_{i+1}$ such that $x \in A_{i+1} \subsetneq A_i$. For each $i \in \Bbb N$, $E_i = A_i \setminus A_{i+1}$. It is clear that $\{E_i\}_i$ is an infinite sequence of non-empty disjoint sets in $M$.
